# Finding the constant part of an algorithms running time

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I have an implementation of an algorithm that runs in O(n log n), for n=10^7 the algorithm takes 570 ms. Does anyone know how to find the constant part (C) of my algorithms running time? I would like to have this so I can calculate how long the algorithm 'should' take for an arbitrary input size.

Comment: Cant you test it out for different values of n and the diff should give you C ?

Comment: @smk I don't think you even need different values.

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question, suppose we know the algorithm requires O(n log n) core operations, how does one find the cost of just one core operation?

Comment: Do you mean the constant in front of the n log n, or the constant of some low-order term?

Comment: Basically given an algorithms complexity and its running time for a specific input size. How would I estimate its running time for any other input size. So for example my algorithm is O(n log n) and takes 570 ms for an input size of 10^7. How would I estimate its running time for an input size of 10^10 for example without actually trying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can calculate it exactly, but if you know for sure that the complexity is `O(n log n)` then I would recommend a simple proportion as an estimate your run time:

```
10^10 log 10^10   unknown run time
--------------- = ----------------
10^7 log 10^7           570 ms
```

In this case, that should be about `1428.6 * 570 ms =~ 814 sec`.

It's not exactly mathematically correct, but if you don't have multiple data points to try to fit to a curve to figure out the various constants, it's not an unreasonable place to start.

Comment: This actually gave me a decent approximation

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the asymptotic complexity of an algorithm is O(n log n), then with just a single data point you can't (exactly) determine the runtime on future operations.  Imagine, for example, that you have an algorithm that you know runs in time O(n) and on an input of size N, the runtime is T.  You can't exactly predict what the runtime is going to be on an input of size 2T, because it's unclear how much of T is explained by the slope of the linear function and how much is explained by the intercept.

If you assume that N is "large enough" that most of the runtime T comes from the slope, then you can make a reasonable estimate of the runtime of the algorithm on a future input.  Specifically, since the function grows linearly, you can assume that if you multiply the size of the input by some constant k, then the runtime ought to be Tk.  In your case, the function n log n grows *mostly* linearly.  Since *log* grows very slowly, for large enough n its growth is extremely flat.  Consequently, if you think that N is "large enough," you can estimate the runtime on an input of size kN by just scaling the runtime on size N by a factor of k.

To be much more accurate, you could also try gathering more data points about the runtime and doing a regression.  In the linear case, if you know two accurate data points, you can recover the actual linear function and then extrapolate to get very accurate runtime predictions.  With something of the form n log n, it's probably good to assume the runtime has the form c<sub>0</sub> n log n + c<sub>1</sub> n + c<sub>2</sub> n.  If you gather enough data points, you could probably plug this into Excel and recover the coefficients, from which you could extrapolate very accurately.

Hope this helps!